# Using javascript code in express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using `nodejs server` to run my app along with `express-handlebars engine as view engine` . I wonder how can I use `javascript code` in  the `view` in order to manipulate data given by the server as illustrated below :

```
// from server 
app.get("/newcalendar", (req, res)=>{ 
rdv.find().
   then(data=>{
        res.render("newcalendar", {servData:data}); 
    })
  .catch(error=>{
    return console.log(error)
  })
});

// to view : newcalendar.hbs , I want to use javascript to manipulate the recieved data :servData
<div>
   {{#each servData}}
        {{this}}  // how can I manupulate this using javascript ?
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: You don't. Prepare your data _before_ rendering, and then pass that as context in your `res.render` (that `{servData:data}` that your code has right now), and then your tamplate can reference keys in that object. Don't try to run code in your template, run it _before_ you template. In this case, you want `servData: data.map(...do the work here...)`

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Please I am a bit lost in your explanation can you write a small example ?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you described _what_ manipulation you would like to do to `servData`.

Comment: Handlebars, like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), tends to be "logicless," meaning you should try and do whatever data transforms you want _before_ you use it within your view. As such, in your route, is it possible to `let newDate = transformData(data); res.render("newcalendar", { servData: newDate});`?